Salesforce is not available to login
I am in Korea and getting salesforce connection failure.
Is there any region having same issue?
We are just waiting comments on the Trust page.

Same issue: https://status.salesforce.com/generalmessages/1476

Same issue here, happened for 2 hours...

is E2C also impacted with delivery failures?

RCA posted by Salesforce: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=003876113&type=1

I’m voting to close this question because StackExchange shouldn't be used to verify someones' problems to connect to Salesforce is due to Salesforce.

I always suggest that people view #TrustSalesforce with a critical eye, because it takes Salesforce a little bit of time to reporting live outages when you need an answer right away on their official page, especially in APAC. However, I imagine your issue is related to this, which was posted a few hours into the outage: https://status.salesforce.com/incidents/13457
Don't get me wrong, #TrustSalesforce absolutely will post details on outages and get them right after-the-fact, but by that time a few hours have gone by and the problem is most likely already resolved.
#DownDetector https://downdetector.com/status/salesforce/ in my opinion is a much quicker way to verify if other Salesforce customers are having issues across the globe vs just an isolated MyDomain/internal company network configuration issue.
